# Loop through specific columns to match conditions and update columns

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I am trying to rebuild some MS Access update query logic with VBA code, as the update logic is missing a few arguments.

[Google drive link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/194ktrSYZQELM1PlxZoXizRXu9BqU6mBrMZy9_dLF_3A/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: table]

In my database "Invoice Account allocation", there are 3 tables:

- Account_Mapping
- Load_ID
- Status_ID.

The default invoice account in tables (`Load_ID` and `Status_ID`) is updated by the invoice account from the Account_Mapping table.

The primary key is "ID" since it exists in tables - Load_ID and Status_ID. The tables Account_Mapping and Load_ID can be joined by:
Origin country & Origin country,
Origin Postal code & Postal code,
Destination country & Destination, and
Destination postal code & Destination postal code.

In the account_mapping table, there are several "isnotnull", it means the string value can take anything.

Using an update query to do this update is not robust. Ideally, a loop should be done to first check the Origin country and then find the matches based on the origin postal code, destination country and the postal code.

```
UPDATE 
   ([Load_ID] 
    INNER JOIN 
    Account_Mapping 
        ON  ([Load_ID].Origin country = Account_Mapping.[Origin country]) AND 
            ([Load_ID].Destination = Account_Mapping.[destination country]) AND 
            ([Load_ID].Origin country = Account_Mapping.[Origin country])) 
    INNER JOIN 
    Status_ID 
        ON [Load_ID].ID = Status_ID.[ID] 
SET 
    [Load_ID].Default Invoice Account = [Invoice Account], 
    Status_ID.[ID] = [Invoice Account]
WHERE 
    ((([Load_ID].Origin country)=));
```

### Ideally a "for" loop

```
'A loop that iterates 4 columns looking for a match based on 4 matches.
'Also, incase of "isnotnull", it simply means ""not empty. 

Dim db as Database
Dim rs as Recordsset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblestudents",dbOpenSnapshot)

my_rs.MoveLast
lastrecord = my_rs.RecordCount

For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount 
    For j = 0 To rs.RecordCount 
        For k = 0 To rs.RecordCount
            'if the [Load_ID].Origin country = Account_Mapping.[Origin country] 
            'And
            ' if the [Load_ID].Origin Postal code = Account_Mapping.[Postal code]
            '     And
            '  if the [Load_ID].Destination country = 
            'Account_Mapping.[Destination]
            '     And
            'if the [Load_ID]. Destination Postal code= 
            'Account_Mapping.[Destination Postal code]
            'update [Load_ID].Default Invoice Account with Account_Mapping.Invoice 'Account
            'for the "isnotnull" criteria, 
            '     Else
            'If Account_Mapping.[Origin Postal code] = "Isnotnull"
            '     Or
            'if the Account_Mapping. Destination= "Isnotnull"
            '     Or
            'if the Account_Mapping. Destination Postal code= "Isnotnull" 
            'update [Load_ID].Default Invoice Account with Account_Mapping.Invoice 'Account
            '   rs.MoveNext
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

rs.Close

Set.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
```

How can I loop over 3 tables, match condition and update the table column values. 
Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Why do you think an Update query is "not robust"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its not robust because, the string value "isnotnull" means that it can any value. With an update query , its difficult to make such a delicate operation.

Comment: In your update query you have a syntax error `[Load_ID].Default Invoice Account` should be `[Load_ID].[Default Invoice Account]`

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are after seems to be an `OUTER JOIN`. This will bring alll records from `LEFT ` table no metter what [Destination postal code] is

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Siyon. Well,  the update query works, the syntax error was a typo. And when it comes to update on multiple conditions and also the fact that many more records would be added, a loop seems to be the ideal option.